# Sentry not logging request payload in .NET

Tags: .net-core, sentry

Recently I started using Sentry for error logs. I use this snippet to connect:

```
webBuilder.UseSentry(o =>
{
    o.Dsn = settings.GetConnectionString("Sentry"); // env variable
    o.AttachStacktrace = true;
    o.TracesSampleRate = 1;
    o.IncludeActivityData = true;
});
```

This works fine and it logs errors but I noticed that request payload is not logged. I looked for some tutorials online and found about `IncludeRequestPayload = true` but in my case it doesn't exist. I use `Sentry.AspNetCore version 3.16.0` within a .NET 3.1. Do you know if it's possible to log the payload with this version and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it myself. For anyone that stumbles upon something like this, you just need to add a `MaxRequestBodySize` to `Sentry.Extensibility.RequestSize.Always`, although not well described in [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/configuration/options/#max-request-body-size).

```
webBuilder.UseSentry(o =>
{
    o.Dsn = settings.GetConnectionString("Sentry");
    o.AttachStacktrace = true;
    o.TracesSampleRate = 1;
    o.MaxRequestBodySize = Sentry.Extensibility.RequestSize.Always; //this line
    o.IncludeActivityData = true;
});
```